# iOS/Swift 4: How to copy a folder containing several folders containing files without removing the files and folders existing destination?

Tags: ios, swift, file, nsfilemanager

I would like to copy a folder containing several folders, and this folders contain several files. If this folders are existing, I would like to keep them inside, and overriding the files if existing. If the files doesn't exist, they are simply naturally added.

```
_ = try FileManager.default.replaceItemAt(previousItemUrl, withItemAt: currentItemUrl)
```

For example:

Files existing on device:

```
APP/XXX/a.txt
APP/XXX/b.txt
APP/XXX/c.txt
APP/YYY/d.txt
APP/ZZZ/e.txt
APP/ZZZ/f.txt
```

Files to copy:

```
APP/XXX/c.txt //Will override
APP/YYY/g.txt //new file added
APP/ZZZ/h.txt //new file added
APP/AAA       //new folder added
```

Do I have to create my self a recursive function, or did that function  already exists natively?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below native method. It copies the source to destination.

```
func copyItem(atPath srcPath: String, 
   toPath dstPath: String) throws
```

We can also control the override use case by implementing other delegate methods mentioned below.

```
optional func fileManager(_ fileManager: FileManager, 
         shouldCopyItemAt srcURL: URL, 
                       to dstURL: URL) -> Bool
```

You can find all these details in [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem)